# How to get clicked query's value?

Tags: javascript

i have some html element and each of them has onclick attribute. and every onclick attribute's value is different. i want to get clicked one's value.

```
<div class="test" onclick="something1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="test" onclick="something3">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="test" onclick="something2">Lorem ipsum</div>

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var test = document.querySelector(`.test[onclick="${e}"]`);
   console.log(test) 
})
```

here i just want to get the clicked div's onclick value.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just binding the event to the desired elements.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.test')).forEach(e => {
  // Add a data-attribute to store the current onclickvalue.
  e.dataset.onclickvalue = e.getAttribute('onclick'); // gets the attribute value.
  e.onclick = ""; // this is to avoid an event call.
  
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.dataset.onclickvalue);
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="test" onclick="something1">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="test" onclick="something3">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="test" onclick="something2">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="something*"` are malformed on-event attributes. The correct syntax is:

> ```
> onclick="something2();"
> ```

Normally an [on-event attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) has a function or statement as its value -- but AFAIK data types and primitive values are never a value of an on-event attribute (but technically anything can be an attribute with a value but it's not standard and it's just plain ugly). Moreover, the use of on-event attributes are generally discouraged and the use of [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) encouraged (the on-event property is neither encouraged nor is it discouraged):

> **on-event attribute:** `<div class="test"` <del>`onclick="callback();"`</del> `>TEST</div>`
>
> **on-event property:** `document.querySelector(".test").onclick = callback;`
>
> **event listener:** `document.querySelector(".test").addEventListener("click", callback);`

Although completely valid, using a div as a clickable element for user interaction is a poor choice. Interactive tags such as `<button>`, `<input>` -- even `<a>` are far better choices because they feature built-in behavior that facilitates user interaction, and UI logic. In addition buttons and links are even better semantically.

1. Assuming that we'll continue with `<div>s` despite of what was previously discussed,
2. we have established that the `onclick` attributes should be removed since:
    
   A. the general use of on-event attributes is discouraged and 
   B. they are syntactically incorrect anyhow.
3. `<div>s` do not have a convenient `value` attribute like `<button>` or `<input>` tags. Fortunately any tag can have a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).  Each `<div>` is assigned `data-value` attribute with a unique value (any string value can be assigned). The value can be accessed with the [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property:

   > ```
   >  var value = document.querySelector(".click").dataset.value; // get value
   >  document.querySelector(".click").dataset.value = '3'; // set value
   > ```
4. An event listener is bound to the document object which is registered to the click event. So if the user clicks anywhere on the page, the event listener will invoke the callback function (ex. `function clickHandler()`). The callback function will determine what is specifically clicked by using the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (ex. `<div class="click">`) property while all other tags are ignored. This process is a part of a programming pattern called **[Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)**.

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
/*
Bind document to the click event
callback is function clickHandler()
*/
document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

// Always have callback functions pass the Event Object
function clickHandler(event) {
  // Reference the clicked tag
  var clicked = event.target;

  /*
  if the clicked tag has the className of '.click'...
  ...get the value of data-value and
  log it to console
  */
  if (clicked.className === 'click') {
    var value = clicked.dataset.value;
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='click' data-value='1'>CLICK 1</div>
<div class='click' data-value='2'>CLICK 2</div>
<div class='click' data-value='3'>CLICK 3</div>
<div class='click' data-value='4'>CLICK 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it sweet and simple, I just write a basic `onclick` method. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

> **You have to provide method name in onclick attribute like `something()`. Not just string**

```js
function something(e) {
  console.log(e.innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="test" onclick="something(this)">something1</div>
<div class="test" onclick="something(this)">something3</div>
<div class="test" onclick="something(this)">something2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getvalue(x)
{
console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<div class="test" onclick="getvalue(1)">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="test" onclick="getvalue(2)">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="test" onclick="getvalue(3)">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

try this code .